# Let $w = e^{sz-\frac{1}{2}t^2}$ where z is a standard wiener process. Find the equation governing w.

Tags: stochastic-processes, partial-derivative, stochastic-calculus, finance, differential

First I applied logarithms to simplify this.
$$
lnw = sz-\frac{1}{2}t^2
$$

Then I found the partial derivatives with respect to $t$ and then $z$.
$$
\frac{\partial lnw}{dt} = -t
$$
$$
\frac{\partial lnw}{dz} = s 
$$

Then I solved both equations for $dlnw$:
$$ 
dlnw = sdz  \hspace{1cm} dlnw = -tdz$$

Putting these together I get what is my solution.
$$dlnw = \frac{1}{2}(sdz - tdz)$$
But this is just plain wrong because we should get an answer the form should be $dw = adt + bdz$.  What am I missing?

The context of the problem comes from a financial mathematics text where we are working with Ito calculus and Wiener processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply Ito’s calculus
$$dw = \frac{\partial w}{\partial z}dz + \frac12 \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial z^2}dz^2+ \frac{\partial w}{\partial t} dt 
= w[sdz +(s^2-t)dt]
$$
where $ dz^2=dt$.

Comment: Ah, this is clicking now.  When I did it I got w[sdz + (0.5s^2 - t)dt].  But why is dz^2 = dt?

Comment: @gunsnfloyd - correct, there is a 0.5. dz^2 = dt because z is a standard Wiener process